# The provided value for the input parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope 'https://graph.microsoft.com/user.readBasic.all' is not valid

Tags: graph, openid, microsoft-graph-api, openid-connect

I am getting 'invalid scope error' while i am trying to get access token for Graph API with MSA(live) account. This is happening only for few MSA accounts not for all the account.

The auth url is

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=<app id>&redirect_uri=<call back url>&response_type=code+id_token&state=state&nonce=c7a966a3-d63d-4348-8ab8-bd445b0e9bb1&response_mode=form_post&scope=openid+email+profile+https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fuser.readBasic.all
```

curl cmd used get access token

```
POST /common/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 3d1ec75e-e0ec-4507-5b4c-fa59f0f71c31client_id=<app id>&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fuser.readBasic.all&redirect_uri=<redirect url>&grant_type=authorization_code&client_secret=<app secret >&code=<code>
```

I am confused why it is working for few accounts.

Comment: Can you provide a capture of the HTTP traffic over the wire?

Comment: Can you also confirm that each of those accounts has an associated email? From the [AAD docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-scopes): 'The email claim is included in a token only if an email address is associated with the user account, which is not always the case.'

Answer (score 1):

To find out why you are getting this inconsistent behavior - we would need to see the error response that you are getting to the token request.  Please update your question with that information.

In the meantime, User.ReadBasic.All is ONLY valid for work or school (i.e. organizational) accounts, and not with MSA. This permission is typically to read other user's profiles (in your organization), and hence is invalid in a consumer scenario.  This is documented here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#user-permissions (in the first line of the *Remarks*).
Is there a reason that your app is requesting this permission for use with an MSA?

Hope this helps,

Comment: Hi Dan, The above subject is error response we are getting when we tried to execute curl command(to generate access token).

Comment: Per the answer, and the error, the permission you requested is not valid for use with a consumer (MSA) user.  That permission is only relevant for organizations (and Azure AD users).  Again is there a reason you are requesting this permission?  Which Microsoft Graph API do you intend to call?

Comment: Thank you for response Dan, Scope params we are asking openid+email+https://graph.microsoft.com/user.readBasic.all. To get id_token we need OpeniD and we are making '/me' from MSGraph api. So as per your comment(permission is only relevant for organizations), i am trying to understand why these scope permission are not working for MSA and why it is suddenly stopped working(previously it is working as expected).

Comment: Why don't you use opened+email+User.Read if all you are doing is GET /me? I'm not sure why this used to work as you are saying. Also, even if it is supported not sure if scope names are case sensitive.  The scope name is User.ReadBasic.All. Also, for Microsoft Graph permissions, you don't need to specify the Graph App URI as a prefix in the scope name.  In terms of more investigation, we would need the full error message - this is a request-client-id and timestamp - it should be either in the HTTP response headers or the full error message.